# Append the filename with part of string in directory in python

Tags: python, design-patterns, match

My folder structure is this way
Root has multiple directories which has multiple files and I want particular pdf to be appended with part of string in directory.

Dir1 -> I_want_apple_in_file_name

Filename ->Fruit

Dir2 -> I_want_Orange_in_file_name

Filename ->Fruit

I want specific part of string which is in fixed position to appended after pdf filename.
My output should be:

Dir1 -> I_want_apple_in_file_name

Filename ->Fruit_apple

Dir2 -> I_want_Orange_in_file_name

Filename ->Fruit_Orange

My code is like this:

```
    pattern ='Fruit_*.pdf'
    file_name = [ os.path.join(r, file) for r, d, f in os.walk(path) for file in f if  fnmatch.fnmatch(file,pattern) ]
    for file in file_name :
      head_tail = os.path.split(file)
      filematch = head_tail[1]
      directory_split = (head_tail[0])
      sec_head_tail =os.path.split(directory_split)
      str = [sec_head_tail[1] ]
```

Now str has directory name. How to store directory name in string and get the position. I was thinking to rename or append the string as suffix in filename. I am a beginner in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question corectly, regular expressions should save you. Basically you want to derive one string from another.

```
def get_file_name(full_path):
    import re
    pattern = "I_want_(.*)_in_file_name"
    result = re.search(pattern, full_path)
    if result:
        fruit = result.groups()[0]
        return f"Fruit_{fruit}"


get_file_name("blah/blah/I_want_apples_in_file_name")
# => returns Fruit_apples
```

If I'm not understanding your question correctly can you please make your question more specific.  Don't tell us about all the things you want to do in life, just the part that's causing problems.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to extract string from directory. I will append the extracted string in the filename.                                                                                                I will make the question more clear going further